# How to put/stream data into an Excel file on sftp

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, xlsxwriter

**What works**

With the following code, I can write the content of `TheList` into a CSV on an SFTP.

```
import paramiko
import csv

# code part to make and open sftp connection

TheList = [['name', 'address'], [ 'peter', 'london']]

with sftp.open(SftpPath + "anewfile.csv", mode='w', bufsize=32768) as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    filewriter.writerows(TheList)
```

**What doesn't work**

With the following code, the Excel file is created on the SFTP, but it is empty. What is false?

```
import paramiko
import xlsxwriter

# code part to make and open sftp connection

TheList = [['name', 'address'], [ 'peter', 'london']]

with sftp.open(SftpPath + "anewfile.xlsx", mode='wb', bufsize=32768) as f:
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(f)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    for row_num, data in enumerate(TheList):
        worksheet.write_row(row_num, 0, data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the [`Workbook`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html). Either using the `with` statement:

```
with sftp.open(SftpPath + "anewfile.xlsx", mode='wb', bufsize=32768) as f, \
     xlsxwriter.Workbook(f) as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    for row_num, data in enumerate(TheList):
        worksheet.write_row(row_num, 0, data)
```

Or call [`Workbook.close`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#workbook-close) explicitly:

```
workbook.close()
```

Comment: jad to remove the bufsize part. Now it works. YOu did help me. You may edit your answer, so I will accept for other users.

Comment: Not like `xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')`. I've meant if you replace `sftp.open` with local `open`, keeping rest of the code. Removing `bufsize` seems like a hack, rather than a solution. Maybe try two nested `with` blocks (of the explicit `workbook.close()`)